# Showing continuity between two metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $K \subset C([0,1])$ such that for each $f \in K$, we have $|f(0)| \leq 10$ and $f$ has Lipschitz constant at most 50. Note that $K$ is in fact a compact subset. This can be shown by the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem but I will omit the details.

We want to show there exists a function $f \in K$ such that $\int_0^1 \cos{f(x)}dx \geq \int_0^1 \cos{g(x)}dx$ for all $g \in K$.

Show: The function $T: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(f) = \int_0^1 \cos{f(x)}$ is continuous.

Since $K$ is compact, by EVT we will get our maximum $f$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. We need some $\delta > 0$ which we will try to determine after our rough work. But we will assume $\|f-g\|_\infty < \delta$.

Now for our rough work.
\begin{align*}
\Big|\int_0^1\cos{f(x)}dx - \int_0^1\cos{g(x)dx}\Big| &= \Big|\int_0^1(\cos{f(x)} -\cos{g(x)})dx\Big| \\
&\leq \int_0^1|\cos{f(x)} -\cos{g(x)}|dx \\
&\leq \int_0^1\|\cos{f(x)} -\cos{g(x)}\|_\infty dx \\
&= \|\cos{f(x)} -\cos{g(x)}\|_\infty
\end{align*}
But now I'm having trouble using the fact that $\|f-g\|_\infty < \delta$ to complete this proof. Perhaps I'm approaching this wrong. Or I'm overlooking some sort of algebraic trick to get rid of the cosines above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already done a lot of the work, good job!

Note that $\cos$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$
(This is because the Lipschitz constant can be bounded
by the $\infty$-norm of the derivative).
Thus we have
$$
|\cos f(x)-\cos g(x)| \leq |f(x)-g(x)|
$$
for all $x\in [0,1]$.
Taking the supremum over these $x$ leads to the estimate
with $\|f-g\|_\infty$ which you need.